# crypto pbkdf2 is not called

Tags: node.js, pbkdf2

I have written an function to hashpasswords with `crypto.obkdf2`. This function was working fine, but for some reason he doesn't anymore.

### EDIT

In a controller I want to create an user with the user.service:

## account.controller:

```
userService.createAccount(details, true, function(err, result){
    if(err){
        res.status(500).json({message: err});
    }else{
        //account is created, details are mailed, now we can set the user on the order  
        user = result;
    }
})
```

The service does a few checks and call the user.register function

## user.service

```
function createAccount (details, generatePassword, callback){
    console.log("createAccount");
    //generate password, save details + password, mail details, send results back in callback
    //if(generatePassword){
    //    details.password = random(10);
    //}
    details.password = '7eb4f68ea4';

    var userData = _.pick(details, 'firstName', 'lastNamePrefix', 'lastName','email','gender', 'password');
    userData.verificationCode = random(8);
    userData.userName = userData.email;
    console.log("userdate", userData);
    User.register(userData, function(err, user){
        console.log("register user", err);

        if(err && (11000 == err.code || 11001 == err.code)) {
            console.log("E-mailadres already in use");
            return callback("E-mailadres already in use");
        }

        if (err) {
            console.log("Something went terribly wrong...", err);
            return callback("Something went wrong: " + err)
        }
        var options = {
            to: user.email,
            subject: 'Uw account op Prisma Note',
            template: 'new-account'
        }
        //Mail sturen met activatielink na aanmaken
        mailService.mail(options, user, null, function(err, data){
            console.log("sendmail!");
            if (err) {
                console.log("error sending mail", err);
                return callback("Error sending mail: " + err.message);
            }else{
                console.log("hier!", user);
                return callback(null, user);
            }
        });

    })
}
```

The user.modal contains the register function:

## user.model

```
User.statics.register = function(opts, callback) {
    console.log("register!");
    var self = this;
    var data = _.cloneDeep(opts);


    passwordService.hash(opts.password, function(err, hashedPassword, salt) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("passwordsrv", err);
            return callback(err, null);
        }

        data.password = hashedPassword;
        data.passwordSalt = salt;
        self.model('User').create(data, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("createuser", err);
                return callback(err, null);
            }

            user.password = undefined;
            user.passwordSalt = undefined;

            callback(err, user);
        })
    })
}
```

And finally, the code comes to the passwordService

## password.service

```
var LEN = 256;
var SALT_LEN = 64;
var ITERATIONS = 10000;
var DIGEST = 'sha256';

function hashPassword(password, salt, callback){
    console.log("hashPassword");
    var len = LEN /2;
    if (3 === arguments.length) {
        crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, ITERATIONS, len, DIGEST, function(err, derivedKey) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("crypto err", err);
                return callback(err);
            }

            return callback(null, derivedKey.toString('hex'));
        })
    } else {
        console.log("pwdsrv");
        callback = salt;
            crypto.randomBytes(SALT_LEN / 2, function(err, salt) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("randombyte", err);
                    return callback(err);    
                }

                salt = salt.toString('hex');
                console.log("hier");

                console.log(password, salt, ITERATIONS, len, DIGEST);
                //password = '7eb4f68ea4'
                //salt = '21aaac28b8411326b8df5b8b60476904f58d40f972a2f5d698ec4d0fb57dc315'
                //ITERATIONS = 10000
                //len = 128
                //DIGEST = 'sha256'
                crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, ITERATIONS, len, DIGEST, function(err, derivedKey) {
                    console.log("hjioo");
                    if (err) { 
                        console.log("pbkdf2", err);
                        return callback(err);
                    }
                    console.log("hier");
                    callback(null, derivedKey.toString('hex'), salt);
                })
            })
    }
}
```

This function is called from our 'user model'. That model has an `User.statics.register` function what we can call. After a lot of debugging lines I have found out the code stops at (in my tested cases) `crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, ITERATIONS, len, DIGEST, function(err, derivedKey)` in the `else` of the function. The log before this function show the content of the variables, but I can't see the logs in the function.

I have no idea, why this is stopped working. We have updated our node.JS version, but since this is an node module, that must be no problem.

Can somebody help me to solve this problem, so our users can register again?

The mailservice, which you can see in the service, sends an email via Amazon SES, I think it is not relevant to post that code.

Comment: as a side note, why are you assigning salt to the callback, as salt is not supposed to be a function?

Comment: @MaxSemikin it's the case where only two arguments are passed, a password and a callback (so the salt should be generated).

Comment: Can you create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which shows which arguments you're passing to `crypto.pbkdf2()`?

Comment: @robertklep I have added more code, so you can see the whole process

Comment: @NVO it's not necessarily more code that's useful, it's how you are calling `crypto.pbkdf2()` (with _specifically_ which arguments). Which digest, which key length, the number of iterations, etc. It may be that it's just taking a lot of time to calculate the derived key.

Comment: @robertklep ah, now I get it. added some code and comments. I think you need this.

Comment: @NVO thnx :D However, using those values and your exact code, the problem isn't reproducable (you could try running it standalone to rule out an issue with the particular Node version that you're using, but I don't think it's a Node bug).

Comment: @robertklep I also think it isn't a Node bug, but I will try to register an account via another route with services and controllers.

Comment: @robertklep hmm via another way, it works fine. So I think the function indeed takes to long to process. Is there a way to wait for a result?

Comment: @NVO if it stalls with the values that you posted, it shouldn't take more than about 50ms to calculate the derived key. There might be something else going on, but it's difficult to say. What's the running environment of your app (own server, VM, Amazon Lambda, ...)? Do you have a reverse proxy (like NGINX) in front of your app? Have you tried using `crypto.pbkdf2Sync()` to see if that works better (it's not really useful in production, but might provide some insights on what's going on)?